# How to implement a class with default type parameter and default constructor param value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to have a class `DataStore` which has the following features:

1. This class type accepts a type parameter `T`, which is `string` default.

   This means:

```js
type StringDataStore = DataStore; // should resolves to DataStore<string>
type NumberDataStore = DataStore<number>; // this should also works !
```

2. The constructor of this class accepts an initial value, whose type should be `T`

   And, the default value is an empty string `""`.

   This means:

```js
// type of d1 should be inferred as MyData<number>
// and d1.initValue === 1
const d1 = new MyData(1);

// type of d2 should be inferred as MyData<string>
// and d2.initValue === ""
const d2 = new MyData();
```

I tried to implement this class like the following:

```js
class DataStore<T = string> {
  private initValue: T;

  public constructor(obj: T = "") {
    this.initValue = obj;
  }
}
```

Apparently, however, the type check will fail because
in the constructor, `'""' is not assignable to type 'T'`

So, is there a way to implement this class ?

Comment: What would you expect `new DataStore<number>()` to do with `initValue` exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex Wayne already pointed out, that you have an issue with `new DataStore<number>()` in your approach.

A generic parameter default for `T` is set and determined by the caller of `DataStore`. But you also want to set a default string *value* in the `DataStore` implementation, so a type mismatch can happen (like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=15&pln=18&pc=16#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwGUEHsBOBTAPAFWgF5oIEMBLAOwHMA%20aAbwChpXoAHCgN0S2ivIIAamBABXLAC5oeANxMWbdmIBGIcsGjA0lUhjHB0GABRoVAKwD80vVWoBKRa2VqNWnXoNHTF6XkdsHKrqmtq6ZF6YPuZ%200AA%20JGR2RNAARKn2jE6B0AgAFuQQAHQCwqISKWbm0JA1lACe8oEAvkytTAj17HyoFDTwSKiYfMQDKEZY8p3d0AByYgC2KlgYY0PYKWsTOJSLyxi08kxhpNAAJgCMKZRYAO5wiOPDxhf28icI5wBM13cPgxNjG9jh5PmcAMy-e5bYY7PYrWhA2TQAD0KOgADMAFTAADW0jOWFAYGwZxqMF2SxWABpoCoxJ9bnwIFhPul%20JQECtKKIQPUFCc0CAsEUQGhqMZjBDyXV6vYSpRBCJxFhMmi0qkgA)).

If you can change the shape of `DataStore` a bit, a safer alternative is to make the constructor `private` and use a factory method:

```
class DataStore<T = string> {
    private initValue: T;

    // allow creation of instances only via static factory methods
    public static create(): DataStore<string>
    public static create<T>(t: T): DataStore<T>
    public static create<T>(t?: T): DataStore<T> {
        return new DataStore(t)
    }

    private constructor(obj: any = "") { // make ctor private
        this.initValue = obj;
    }
}

type StringDataStore = DataStore; // DataStore<string>
type NumberDataStore = DataStore<number>; // DataStore<number>

const d4 = DataStore.create(1); // DataStore<number>
const d5 = DataStore.create(); // DataStore<string>
const d6 = DataStore.create<number>(); // error (good, we prevent the mentioned mismatch)

console.log((d5 as any).initValue) // ""
```

[Sample playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=41&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwGUEHsBOBTAPAFWgF5oIEMBLAOwHMA+aAbwChpXoAHCgN0S2ivIIAamBABXLAC5oeANxMWbAPRLookGgDu0YNkTk0laGgBm-SqTCVgWGIZABPaF3JgSSBOWDQTYYOgwnAFssBAALNAATCEVWdjEAIxAvd31vXSxeAAoASml4JFRMXFIKGlpYjkTk70tPdL0EXDxaLIRpPDy4RBQA5oq2KqSUupSM3nxWhAB+Dq6C3uLJxkrB7AQxDCNKLG0Fouw2nMqAXwVBznIeJp1DUrF-TCy0BIAraSsnYgAib5zGaAqaBBMAAaz4jwwHG4vFWbHC5AgADoBMJRBIiMY3vJBmczkwEA52HxUGVqPs+piKcVZIDVNTsDhSlQ6ASiXwAHJiIIJLAYBl8YgCnCUbm8jC0WlA4Winl8ipMYB3BDQSIAFipPQOWCR4yaWQAjDkpfStX0RWL5YrlaqAKyawp9XWNLC5E3dR1LZnla0WFWRABsDsW2GdmSaFrlErddOgfIwmGgWWoaCiABpoJo+JwsFwsJQVeE+CECwYdpFgYiQQhgGFjr6IGgQDqNNQsllIvbIGpKA4cijKIIROIsP8gb8gA)

Answer (score 1):

Your types are correct but your code is not type safe as is, which is what typescript is complaining about. The problem is not the default type, but the default value. The default type may be anything, but the default value is *always* as string.

Right now would set `initValue` to the string `""` when you call `new DataStore<number>()`, which should be illegal.

I think you need to rethink your approach here. You can't make runtime decision based on a generic type, since types don't exist at runtime. So you can't inspect when the generic type is, and create an appropriate default value.

I think the only way to work with this is to remove the default, and make the consumer pass in a type and/or default value explicitly.

```
class DataStore<T> {
  private initValue: T;
  public constructor(obj: T) {
    this.initValue = obj;     
  }  
}

new DataStore('some string')
new DataStore(123)
new DataStore<'foo' | 'bar'>('foo')
```